# GDAL bindings problem with ArcMap 10.1 Python tool

Tags: python, gdal, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

I'm really getting mad with this. ArcGIS sometimes can be so just...irritating!
Forgive me if this question is by any means duplicating [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31455/importing-gdal-from-arcgis-python-window-is-it-possible) or similar ones, but I really can't find my way out of this problem.

I have a x64 Windows Server 2012 machine (pretty cutting-edge, isn't it?) and a 32-bit ArcMap 10.1 installation on it, as well as a 64-bit ArcGIS Server installation.
I came up with having two different Python 2.7 installations on my machine, both placed by ArcGIS:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\     #32 bit Python 2.7
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\  #64 bit Python 2.7
```

Now, what I want to do is to make an ArcMap tool which peforms calls to GDAL 1.9 Python binding library. My tool starts with a standard import of the gdal bindings:

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import *
[...]
```

I therefore installed (using gisinternals.com/sdk msi installers) BOTH 32 AND 64 bit GDAL core binaries and binding libraries, so I have:

```
#GDAL core binaries
C:\Program Files\GDAL       #64 bit
C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL #32 bit

#GDAL bindings
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\osgeo     #32 bit
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib\site-packages\osgeo  #64 bit

#PATH environment variable
echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL;[...]
```

If I try to import the gdal bindings via both the Python interpreters, I get the followings:

```
C:\>C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe -m gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 29, in
 <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 25, in
 swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

C:\>C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\python.exe -m gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_mai
n
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in <module
>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21,
 in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17,
 in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

and the very same error is given by the ArcMap Python shell when I try to run the tool:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\processors\URBAN_CLASS\URBAN_CLASS.py", line 2, in <module>
    import GLCM_wrapper.GLCM_wrapper
  File "C:\processors\URBAN_CLASS\GLCM_wrapper\GLCM_wrapper.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gdal
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 25, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

In addition, I tried to have the sys.path printed out from the ArcMap Python shell:

```
['C:\\processors\\URBAN_CLASS',
u'c:\\program files (x86)\\arcgis\\desktop10.1\\arcpy',
'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\Lib',
'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\Lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Windows\\system32',
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\bin',
'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1',
'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\arcpy',
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts']
```

Any hint/idea on how to make my tool correctly import the gdal bindings?
I'm completely stuck!

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to make it work...Hope this is useful for others, too.

1. I re-installed the GDAL 1.9 bindings using the proper installer in this page http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-9-mapserver-6-2.zip which lists the GDAL core binaries and bindings components that are compiled daily using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 compiling environment
2. Then, I installed what appears to be an [ESRI-made Python binding library for GDAL 1.8](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1eec30bf5fa042a5a2227b094db89441) (I am using 1.9, anyway...).

Seems to work.

They say: "have faith" - I will.