# Conflict between ArcPy and GDAL/OGR?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, gdal, ogr, importerror

## TL;DR

I can't get an installation free version of GDAL/OGR to work from within ArcMap 10.0. I get an `ImportError: DLL load failed` on  `_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)`.

Below, more details on the context and a procedure on how to reproduce the error.

---

Someone in the comments specified that arcpy and GDAL work fine together on his machine. What could be the differences between our configurations (software installed, environment variables, ...)?

## Description of my issue

### What I am trying to do...

I want to deploy an ArcMap 10.0 ToolBox with scripts that use external libraries. I would like to avoid having any manipulation done on the user side: ideally, no additional installation/manipulation should be required for the user. For that reason, I embed the libraries files inside the ToolBox.

### What my problem is...

When I try to use gdal/ogr from osgeo along with arcpy, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_to_script\debugDepl.py", line 32, in <module>
    from osgeo import ogr
  File "path_to_script\osgeo\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "path_to_script\osgeo\__init__.py", line 26, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

There are some binding errors that I don't understand. It seems that there is a conflict between arcpy and gdal/ogr (more information below)

Related:

- [GDAL bindings problem with ArcMap 10.1 Python tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59457/gdal-bindings-problem-with-arcmap-10-1-python-tool)
- [gdal ImportError in python on Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/gdal-importerror-in-python-on-windows)
- [Conflict arcpy (Arc 10) and gdal?](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/29356)
- [Running GDAL and arcpy together](http://benmearns.blogspot.be/2013/04/running-gdal-and-arcpy-together-arcgis.html)
- [How to run OGR in ArcGIS Scripts?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74524/how-to-run-ogr-in-arcgis-scripts)

---

## How to reproduce the error

If you can help me achieve want I want, it might be useful if I explain every step that lead to this error. I tried to detail as much as I could so that you could reproduce it.

**1/** On a Windows 7 64bits machine, Install ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 (32 bits)

**2/** [Download GDAL‑1.11.0.win32‑py2.6.exe Windows binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

**3/** Install that library with your Python installation

**4/** Move the associated library files (`path_to_python_install\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages`) to another new folder (osgeo folder + several Python files)

**5/** Create a Python script in that folder and edit it in your favorite Python editor and check that you can import gdal/ogr

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
```

**6/** Try importing arcpy from the script before and after importing gdal/ogr

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import gdal 
import arcpy
```

That should work, now try the other way around

```
import arcpy
# Maybe some environment variable settings
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import gdal
```

And that version should create the error.

**7/** Create a toolbox (or call the script from within ArcMap) with the version that worked standalone. And try to run it within ArcMap (should fail).

### Notes on the steps

**1/** I've found some official Python bindings but only for ArcMap 10.1

**2/** This distribution includes a complete GDAL installation. It is a 32bit version for my 32bit version of Python26.

**4/** As specified [in these recommendations for scripts deployment](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/06/a-simple-approach-for-including-3rd-party-python-libraries-with-your-scripts/), I should copy the library files directly. I want to avoid the user to have to install things as much as possible

**5/** This may (or may not) require some environment variable settings:

```
import os
environList = os.environ['PATH'].split(';')
environList.insert(0, r'path_to_folder\osgeo')
os.environ['PATH'] = ';'.join(environList)
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = r'path_to_folder\osgeo\data\gdal'
```

[GDAL Documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) specifies that we should:

- Add the installation directory bin folder to your system PATH, remember to put a semicolon in front of it before you add to the existing path.
- Create a new user or system variable with the data folder from your installation.

[Developers on this blog page](http://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/) seemed to have that error when the environment variables were incorrect.

**6/** It seems that  for some reason if you import arcpy first and ogr/gdal second, gdal is no longer able to find the dll's that it requires. This could have been due to some environment variable settings but the modification I proposed at step 5) didn’t change anything.

**7/** But then my guess is that arcpy is automatically imported (first) so we’re back to the 2nd version of 6)

### Some more information about my attempt to understand what is going on

From PyScripter:

```
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> gdal.__file__
'C:\\Python26\\ArcGIS10.0\\lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\gdal.pyc'
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.__file__
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.0\\arcpy\\arcpy\\__init__.pyc'
```

Alright, the library files were found where they are supposed to be. But then…

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 25, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Maybe something happened to the environment variables or to the python path when importing Arcpy? Well, it doesn't seem  like it...

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> envBefore = os.environ
>>> pyPathBefore = sys.path
>>> import arcpy
>>> envAfter = os.environ
>>> pyPathAfter = sys.path
>>> envBefore == envAfter
True
>>> pyPathBefore == pyPathAfter
True
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run OGR in ArcGIS Scripts?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74524/how-to-run-ogr-in-arcgis-scripts)

Comment: It doesn't seem like a duplicate to me, mainly because this version is 10.1. Also, I've tried my way with GDAL core + bindings from gisinternals but without success (and less importantly for the deployment reasons that I evoked, the Windows binary solution would be better for me).

Comment: Never mind, I read that backwards. However, I do still question why you are moving the files around manually instead of setting environment variables.

Comment: Because in the end I want to be able to give one thing to the user without him having to download and install anything. I'm moving files around because I want to distribute those files as well.

Comment: I recommend trying to get it to work in a simple environment first (without moving things around) and then go from there. If it works without all of that then you are missing something; if not then there's some other issue.

Comment: I have already tried without moving files around and I didn't manage to get it to work...

Comment: Try with the  Christoph Gohlke [GDAL/OGR](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) version

Comment: That's the version I used in the process I described

Comment: This is probably what [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) feels like. The best solution is probably to leave ArcGIS' Python installation alone and install another for custom packages (e.g. Python27 64-bit).

Comment: @MikeT Unfortunately, I'm not sure how that would solve the issue as I need to run scripts from ArcGIS (and avoid additional installs on the user's machine). It's the first time I ever hear about DLL Hell. Now I wish I never had! Has anyone tried the procedure I described?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the issue is the GDAL 1.11 bindings you're fetching from gohlke do not match the internal GDAL inside of Arc*. Your bindings need to be compiled against ESRI's GDAL to work reliably. It's possible they can be made to work, but it is going to be a lot of headache.

In short, ESRI needs to provide the gdal_i.lib stub file that GDAL generates as part of its compilation process, and you need to build the Python bindings against that. I don't know that ESRI provides this, however.

Maybe ESRI could be requested to provide a gdal.py and GDAL bindings as part of ArcPy? Alternatively, maybe you could use [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona) and [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) to replicate the GDAL bindings parts you need. These have the benefit of not needing to link against the ESRI GDAL and instead are able to use it by doing C API calls directly into the DLL.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I have done something wrong but I have a similar issue: importing fiona/rasterio works fine until I try to import arcpy beforehand. I then get an `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.` on line `from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, Session, WritingSession`

Answer (score 1):

Gdal PYthon binding works with conjuration with gdal. You need to have installed GDAL along with the binding to work.

A quick skim over the errors you provided they suggest that while you installed gdal-python you haven't install the gdal by itself:

A possible solution chain is:

1. Install GDAL ([Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php))
2. [Append](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) the installation path to the "PATH" variable for your computer
3. Then install gdal-python for any python interpreters you are using (including arcgis)

A more in-depth tutorial can seen [here](https://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, as I have mentioned, gdal-python does work with the ArcGIS python interpreter -- which is the only one installed on my machine, but conflicts with arcpy (see step 6). This tutorial is fine to install GDAL on Windows but doesn't solve the arcpy/GDAL conflict that I'm facing.

Comment: very strange, I don't have the same behavior - everything imports ok, with whatever order I choose to make the imports. Are you absolutely sure gdal is installed correctly in your machine? You can check it by opening the console (winkey-r -> `cmd`) and typing gdalinfo -version

Comment: In the ideal case, I'd like to use it only with the files -- which I don't see why I couldn't. That's something I can do without arcpy. Anyway, I had already tried installing it with the link you provided and checked that GDAL was correctly installed on my machine (GDAL 1.11.0, released 2014/04/16). What would you suggest that I check to figure out why it works on your machine and not on mine...?