# Installing GDAL and fiona module in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, arcgis-10.0, installation, importerror

I am getting message like this:

```
<font color="#ff0000" face="courier new"> <br>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.</font>
```

Comment: -1 I recommend the following improvements to your post: 1) Provide a clear question, 2) Describe the steps you performed leading up to the error message 2) clean-up the formatting.  Once these issues are cleared up, I would be happy to upvote your post.  Additionally, you are more likely to get answers if you spend time and effort on your questions.

Answer (score 4):

> DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

simply means that GDAL is improperly installed (line 17: missing dll file or rather, that the dll file is not installed at the requested location)

Look also at [Importing GDAL from Python window of ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31455) and [Running GDAL and arcpy together (ArcGIS 10.1, GDAL 1.9.2, python 2.7.4)](http://benmearns.blogspot.be/2013/04/running-gdal-and-arcpy-together-arcgis.html)